# Laravel Has Many through relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through, eloquent-relationship

I am new in laravel and I am facing issue with relationships.
I have three tables.

```
asset            assetmaintenance              users
id               id                            id
name             asset_id                      name
                 inspector_id(users_id)
                 name
```

I want to access all users attached with asset through `assetmaintenance`, so I define relationship in asset model like:

```
    public function users(){

        return $this->hasManyThrough(TenantUser::class,AssetMaintenance::class,'asset_id','id');
    }
```

But the query generated by eloquent is different from what I expected:

```
select * from `assets` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `assets_maintenance` on `assets_maintenance`.`id` = `users`.`id` where `assets`.`id` = `assets_maintenance`.`asset_id` and `username` like ?) and `isDeleted` = ? order by `id` desc
```

I want relation like `assets_maintenance.inspector_id= users.id` but it's comparing `assets_maintenance.id = user.id`.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(TenantUser::class, AssetMaintenance::class, 'inspector_id', 'id');
}
```

And also try with additional parameters

For More
[Laravel Has-Many-Through Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this way

first, create a method in asset model for hasMany assetmaintenance and then after create another method in model for hasOne inspector_id and to fetch all those data in one query use below code.

```
Assets::with('assetmaintenance','assetmaintenance.user')->get()
```